# Duplicate entry for key. even though it is not

Tags: mysql, insert, errors

[image]

Above image describes my tables 'Details'
[image]
And above is my entire table only one row. and  i have tried 'INSERT' to table

```
INSERT INTO `details`( 
  `Name`, 
  `dob`, 
  `age`, 
  `qualification`, 
  `ExpYr`, 
  `ExpMnth`, 
  `Email`, 
  `Contact`, 
  `resume`)
VALUES (
  'viviek',
  '0899-06-21',
  '1117',
  'hihh',
  '2',
  '3',
  '1026viivek@gmail.com',
  '9645904409',
  'Array')
```

but it showing an error like

> Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'Contact'

Why is it showing error with different value than key value in table for contact?

Comment: Off question but ... storing both dob and age? Also your test subject seems to have been born under Nero and lived to hear The Beatles play.

Comment: Storing, rather than computing, an age is problematic -- it will be wrong within a year.

Comment: In the old days of "land lines", everyone in a household shared the same phone number.  Don't make that `UNIQUE`.  Ditto for `email`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the maximum possible stored value for the `int(11)` (32-bit signed integer) `Contact` column is `2147483647`.

MySQL is silently ignoring the fact that the value `9645904409` is larger than this & is "truncating" it down to `2147483647`. Multiple values truncated to `2147483647` are causing the unique constraint violation.

If `Contact` is supposed to be a phone number, I suggest changing the datatype to `VARCHAR(20)` or similar.

Comment: for a 10 digit number , whether i need to set 'VARCHAR(20)'. can i save memory??

Comment: The savings is not worth the hassle when a use includes dashes or leading country code or trailing extension.  `INT` takes 4 bytes; `VARCHAR(...)` for a phone number takes as many bytes as are in the number (10 in your example).